# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ populate: [] }" at path "_id" for model "modelName". NodeJS mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

{ MongooseError [CastError]: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ populate: [] }" at path "_id" for model "Portfolio"

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB ObjectIds are hexadecimal character `strings`, like `5d6ede6a0ba62570afcedd3a`.  You can't parse an object into an ObjectId.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#examples